# The epsilon-delta formulation of limit not existing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So $\lim_{x \to x_0}{f(x)}=L$ can be formulated with a precise $\varepsilon-\delta$ statement that goes something like $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(0<|x-x_0|<\delta\rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon|)$$
I'm wondering how can I formulate an $\varepsilon-\delta$ statement for a limit that doesn't exists, i.e. f(x) has no limit at $x_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is not the limit of $f$ at $x_0$ if

$(\exists \epsilon >0)(\forall \delta >0) \ ((0<|x-x_0|<\delta)\wedge\neg(|f(x)-L|<\epsilon))$

or equivalently,

$(\exists \epsilon >0)(\forall \delta >0) \ ((0<|x-x_0|<\delta)\wedge(|f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon))$

If the last statement is true for all $L$, then we say $f$ has no limit at $x_0$.

Comment: So, we'd just put a $\forall L$ in front of it?